# How to remove header of unknown length using Python

Tags: python, graph, header, plot, csv

Python beginner here. I am using the matplotlib library to make graphs from tab delimited text files. I want my script to be flexible, so that it can take different types of data file and turn them into graphs. The key issue I have is that different text files have different numbers of header lines before the data begins. I would like to have a way for Python to figure out how many lines the header is, then remove them.

I think this could be done in two ways:

1) Count the most frequently occuring number of columns/elements per line in file, as most lines will be columns containing the data of interest. Then with a for loop, remove all lines that do not contain this number of columns.

2) Count number of columns/elements in last row of file, then remove any rows not matching this length. As in all the files I use the last row is also the data, this would work too.

If anyone can show me a short way to do this in python to integrate into my script that would really help a lot.

Many thanks,

Rubal

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable idea. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I should also add that after this is done I will in addition delete the first remaining line encase there is a header with an equal number of columns above the data (which is often the case with my data). I work with large genomic datasets so losing one line of data is ok.

Comment: I am afraid i haven't tried anything much yet beyond setting up a for loop:for line in inputfile: #iterates over each line in the inputfile
 line = line.rstrip() 
 fields = line.split("\t")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
# lines = lines parsed out of file
line_store = {}
for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split('\t')
    if len(tokens) in line_store:
        line_store[len(tokens)].append(line)
    else:
        line_store[len(tokens)] = [line]
most = []
for line_group in line_store.values():
    if len(line_group) > len(most):
        most = line_group
```

`most` will end up being the list you want

2)

```
# lines = lines parsed out of file
tokens_in_last_line = len(lines[-1].split('\t'))
lines_with_correct_number_of_tokens = []
for line in lines[:-2]:
    if len(line.split('\t')) == tokens_in_last_line
        lines_with_correct_number_of_tokens.append(line)
lines_with_correct_number_of_tokens.append(lines[-1])
```

`lines_with_correct_number_of_tokens' will have all your lines with the same number of tokens as the last line in the file.

Both these solutions have major flaws though.  (1) will choke if you have a header with the same number of tokens as the content rows, or if the header rows outnumber the content rows.  (2) will choke if you have a footer line, or if the last line is blank, or, again, if your header rows have the same number of tokens as your content rows.  I think you should see if you could come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: thanks for these! You are right about the flaws. To mitigate this somewhat I will additionally delete one header line after this is done. This should cover me in most cases, if not then an error should be thrown when i try and plot the data and here I will have to manually correct the files.

Comment: Also you are right that a more elegant solution would be better. If anyone can think of one I'd gladly use it. The above was all i could come up with for the problem of files with variable header lengths.

Comment: Sorry newbie question again but how do i get lines parsed out of my file for 'lines'? Thank you

Comment: You could at least improve it by iterating bottom up through the file and stopping on the first line that had the wrong number of tokens.  Though you'd still have the footer and last line blank problems, as well as a problem if the last header line had the same number of tokens as the content rows.  Ultimately, you need some metadata about the files.  Maybe a regex that would check the rows for the right content types in the various fields (so you would ignore a header line with row labels, for instance).

Comment: Just Google around for file handling in Python.  That's quite easy to find.